# android edittext listener

Tags: android, listener, android-edittext

what are the main differences between editText.setKeyListener(this) and editText.setOnKeyListener(this)?

Answer (score 6):

For general use you should probably stick to [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) for listening to text changes. Altering the key listeners will affect the way the `EditView` works if not used properly.

Answer (score 1):

The difference (or lack thereof) can be found in the documentation.

`void setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener)` is a method on View.

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnKeyListener%28android.view.View.OnKeyListener%29):

> Register a callback to be invoked when a key is pressed in this view.

`void setKeyListener(KeyListener)` is a method on the TextView.

From [the documentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setKeyListener%28android.text.method.KeyListener%29)

> Sets the key listener to be used with this TextView. This can be null to disallow user input. Note that this method has significant and subtle interactions with soft keyboards and other input method: see `KeyListener.getContentType()` for important details. Calling this method will replace the current content type of the text view with the content type returned by the key listener.
>
> Be warned that if you want a TextView with a key listener or movement method not to be focusable, or if you want a TextView without a key listener or movement method to be focusable, you must call setFocusable(boolean) again after calling this to get the focusability back the way you want it.

Comment: It appears that my links did not catch the closing parenthesis, does someone know how I can explicitly add it to the link?

Comment: You might try the link button, which will allow you to give your links a text label.

Comment: Hmmm... I never noticed that before.  I always tried to use the 'special' formatting in the textbox itself.  Thanks!